# Linq Statement between IList and datatable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a IList that i got after quering by linq to entities from one table.  And by some                                   other means i got a datatable as well that represent a table in database. Both tables have same columns. i want to search out those EmployeeIDs that are available in IList but not in datatable.  Any please suggest how ican do that by using linq statement. I searched on net and found many clauses but still i am confused how to do that.

For example i found this code on post

```
from c in db.Customers
where !db.Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == c.ProductID)
select c;
```

Comment: Can you post your `DataTable` code?

Comment: Just assume that both have [ID , EmployeeID , Name , Designation] columns and i have to search on the basis of EmployeeID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these:

```
DataTable dt; //your datatable

var results = from c in db.Customers
              where !db.Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == c.ProductID)
              select c;
```

You could then do:

```
var ids = results
    .Where(r => !dt.Rows.AsEnumerable
        .Any(d => d.ItemArray["EmployeeID"] == r.EmployeeID)
    .Select(r => r.EmployeeID);
```